# iOS In-App purchase - closest value vs prices on the website?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm newbie if it comes to the in-app purchase subject. I'm the manager of the online finance web project, where users can buy different types of year's subscription.

We have also the mobile app for iOS, Android and Windows Phone. On Android platform, users can buy only one type of the subscription.
Price is the same as on the website (value in PLN currency). Currently we work on the possibility, to buy two types of the subscription via iOS (in-app purchase).

Unfortunately, in iTunes Connect you can't set a custom price of a product (in PLN currency) - you can choose only predefined tiere.

I can't find similar tiere to my prices available on the website. What should I do? They should be a bit higher or lower vs prices on the website (to get as far as a similar amount in EUR)? I can't set identical prices. Is this not a problem vs Apple Apps Guidelines?
Thanks in advance for any info.

Best,
Jakub

Comment: You have to pick a price tier.  If you can't find one you like then don't use in-app purchase.  Remember that you will give Apple 30% of the in-app purchase price so it is probably reasonable that your in-app price is 30% higher than your web price - but you can't direct people from your app to the web to purchase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it would be not fair to raise the price for about 30% just because someone wants to buy it via mobile.  Ok, I'll try to find price tier closest to the ones, I have on the website. Thanks :)

Comment: Fair enough.  You either need to adjust your web pricing to match the in-app pricing or accept the fact that they will be different

Comment: And accept that prices are different in different countries, and that the money you receive is different in different countries, due to taxes etc. And read the documentation how to display the price of a purchase in your application correctly.

Comment: @Paulw11 is there a way to opt out of the in app purchasesif pricing tiers are not meeting our billing?.

Comment: No. You must pick one of Apple's price tiers.